# how to write two hub which has server method runs in while loop and send data to SignalR client

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, websocket, signalr

I have requirement to show live stock data and at the same time notification on the same page.I have used angular js,dot net signalR and put two while loop which will listen to streamer and push data to client but its not giving expected result.

**//First Client**

```
var stockFeedHub = $.connection.stockFeedHub;
    $.connection.hub.start();
    $.connection.hub.logging = true;
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        stockFeedHub.server.send("-1");
    })
    .fail(function () { console.log('Could not connect stockFeedHub'); });

    stockFeedHub.client.sendStocksData = function (data) {
}
```

**//Second Client**

```
var notificationFeedHub = $.connection.notificationFeedHub;
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        notificationFeedHub.server.getNotification();
    })
    .fail(function () { console.log("fail"); });

    notificationFeedHub.client.sendNotification = function (data) {
//some logic
    }
```

**//Hub one-**

```
 public class NotificationFeedHub : Hub
    {
        public void GetNotification()
        {
                while (true)
                {
                    //NotificationMessage I am getting from Redis.
                    //Call Client method to send notification.

                    Clients.All.sendNotification(notificationMessage));
                    Thread.Sleep(1000*5);
                }
        }

    }
```

**//2nd Hub class**

```
public class StockFeedHub: Hub
        {
            public void Send()
            {
                    while (true)
                    {
                        //I am getting stockLiveData from streamer server.
                        //Call Client method to send sendStocksData.

                        Clients.All.sendStocksData(stockLiveData));
                        Thread.Sleep(1000*5);
                    }
            }

        }
```

I am facing issue due to while loop and i am not sure what else i can do if i want to get both data continuously.

Comment: So what is your expected result and what is your error or not working?

Comment: Delete the while loop in both methods.

Comment: @Danscho I jsut need to show two live stream to my customer one for stock data and second for notifications and both of these data i am getting from stream server.

Comment: @MarcusH If i delete while loop how would you suggest to send continuous stock price and notification to users who are on our site.

Comment: brokkc answered it right on the spot. Delete the while loop and let the hub handle signalR requests. Create a different method that handles you redis updates and call the hub from there

Comment: @AbhayKumar how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You're currently using the web clients to trigger the push, then stealing the request thread each time the request is made and blocking it with a sleep. Don't steal SignalR's threads, rather create your own thread or use one that is already running and there for you.

In this case your stock streamer should have its own thread that is raising stock update events. If so call your StockFeedHub and dispatch your stock updates to all clients when you receive a new stock update.

```
void HandleNewStockMessage(StockModel stock){
  GlobalHost
    .ConnectionManager
    .GetHubContext<StockFeedHub>()
    .Clients.All.sendStocksData(stock);
}
```

More information on Signalr [calling hubs](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#callfromoutsidehub).

I'm not sure how you're using Redis I guess you're using it for your backplane. If so then check the [scaleout with redis](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/scaleout-with-redis) document. You should only need to dispatch your notifications (similar to your stock data) when you receive them and your backplane will scale the messages out.